# Concatenate two pretrained model Error: The name "input_1" is used 2 times in the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate two pre-trained models with the same name in Keras. so far I've renamed all the layers as you can see as follows:

```
  model1 = load_model('./new/CNN_Level1_2Dense_1024ML_Prep_ALL')
  model1.input._name = model1.input.name + '_1'
  for layer in model1.layers:
      layer._name = layer.name + str("_1")
      
  model1._name = 'pretrained_model1'

  print('=====================================')

  model2 = load_model('./new/CNN_Level1.1_2Dense_1024ML_Prep_ALL')
  model2.input._name = model2.input.name + '_2'
  for layer in model2.layers:
      layer._name = layer.name + str("_2")

  model2._name = 'pretrained_model2'
  
  out1 = model1.output
  out2 = model2.output

  m_model = concatenate([out1, out2])
  relu_dense = Dense(19, activation='relu')(m_model)
  output = Dense(19, activation='softmax')(relu_dense)
  
  merged_model = Model(inputs=[model1.input,model2.input], outputs=output)
```

but I still get this error:

> File "Ali_text_classification-Copy1.py", line 196, in train_network
> merged_model = Model(inputs=[model1.input,model2.input], outputs=output)
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
> result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 120, in **init**
> self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
> result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 204, in _init_graph_network
> self.inputs, self.outputs)
> File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1001, in _map_graph_network
> str(all_names.count(name)) + ' times in the model. '
> ValueError: The name "input_1" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just as a sanity check after changing your model's input names just save them individually and check if the name changes are reflected.

Comment: I checked, but the name changes are not reflected. I don't know what to do now

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2021, based on one explanation here, I was able to modify FPN model to Siamese FPN. The link as below:

```
https://github.com/asifpatankar/Siamese_FPN
```

Disappeared 2 times error. Maybe it can help!